# How to add more than an affiliations to an author

Tags: overleaf, ieeetran

I'm trying to add more 2 affiliations to the first author. One of the affiliation is shares with the other authors.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read [bare_conf.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_conf.tex). Please pay attention to the comments in the corresponding positions, which should meet your needs. The following contents are all from this sample file.

> For over three affiliations, or if they all won't fit within the width of the page, use this alternative format:

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for IEEE Conferences}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},
Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology,
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\ Email: see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc., 123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210--4321}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]